# Sharing a custom Qt Widget with different projects using CMake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, shared-libraries

I have written a custom Qt Widget, now I would like to use this widget in other projects. What is the approach to share it? Create a shared library?

Does the project require a specific structure to be shared (like all header files in a separate include directory) or can I just use the normal projects structure?

Is there a simple example that I could start with?

Comment: ***Does the project require a specific structure to be shared (like all header files in a separate include directory)*** No but that may make it easier for you to manage.

Comment: ***I just use the normal projects structure?*** What is normal for 1 person is can be different. All of my hundreds of projects (Qt + CMake) have src and include folders.

Comment: Sure, you're right. I haven't seen the structure with include directory very often, the projects I work with mostly have a src directory with .cpp and .h files in it, that is "my" normal structure. 
Can you share an example projects?

Comment: I am not sure if I have anything that is simple. I have worked with `CMake` for over a decade. Each project imports a long list of helper modules and scripts that I have written for CMake.

Comment: You may want to start with the examples in the CMake wiki. That is where I stared.